# How to curry a function with one argument

Tags: scala

I want to apply all the values to a function, only execute it later. Something like:

```
def foo(i: Int) = 2 * i
val bar: () => Int = foo(1)_
println(bar()) // expect 2
```

But I get a _ must follow method; cannot follow Int error. I have some examples where they use  Function.curried, but I do not find that in my version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val bar = () => foo(1)
// bar: () => Int = <function0>

bar()
// res3: Int = 2
```